# How does the data descriptor priority work in python

Tags: python

I was reading this thing from the internet

> For objects, the machinery is in `object.__getattribute__`which
>   transforms `b.x` into `type(b).__dict__['x'].__get__(b, type(b)).`
>
> The implementation works through a precedence chain that 
>   **gives data descriptors priority over instance variables**,   and **instance variables priority over non-data descriptors**,  and assigns lowest priority to **getattr** if provided.

I didn't understand what does it mean by "giving data descriptor priority over instance variable" and  "instance variables priority over non-data descriptors"

Can anyone give me example how this practically works i want to see what thing has priorty in code

Comment: look at the example code in [@blckknght's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14787522/4279) to [the related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14787334/4279).

Comment: I realise this is an old question but see also https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#descriptor-protocol especially if new to data/non-data descriptors

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each object has a dictionary of attributes that contains it's variables and functions. Referring to these dictionaries:

```
If an instance’s dictionary has an entry with the same name as a data descriptor,    
the data descriptor takes precedence. If an instance’s dictionary has an entry with
the same name as a non-data descriptor, the dictionary entry takes precedence.
```

This is what they were talking about.

To show this:

```
#data descriptor
class A(object):
   def __get__(self, obj, type):
       print "hello from get A"
   def __set__(self, obj, val):
       print "hello from set A"
#non data descriptor
class B(object):
   def __get__(self, obj, type):
       print "hello from get B"

class C(object):
   #our data descriptor
   a = A()
   #our non data descriptor
   b = B()

>>> c = C()
>>> c.a
hello from get A
>>> c.b
hello from get B
>>> c.a = 0
hello from set A
>>> c.a          #notice after reassignment, A.__get__ is still called
hello from set A
>>> c.b = 0     #instance variable with the same name as the non data-descriptor
>>> c.b         #notice how B.__get__ isn't called anymore
0
```

Basically it is saying that when `__get__` and `__set__` are user defined for an object (data descriptor), they will be called instead of the default methods. If only `__get__` is user defined for an object(non-data descriptor), the instance can reassign am instance variable.

So when calling `g.x = 0`: if x is a data descriptor then x's user-defined `__set__` method is called, when x is an instance variable, or non-data descriptor the default behavior is called.

With a **data descriptor**, the class  is controlling all access and modification to the variables. **All access to variables of your data descriptor type will go through `__get__` and `__set__`**. So `c.a = 0` calls `A.__set__` and c.a is changed how the class defined it. There is no way to create an instance variable 'c.a' that is not of the type A.

With a **non data descriptor**, the class only controls access, so when `c.b = 0` is called, since `__set__` isn't defined, a new instance variable is made(the default behavior). There is no user-defined behavior on setting the variable, so you can create an instance variable with the same name, without the `__get__` behavior.

The precedence they are talking about is the dynamics of the two. A data descriptor will always call `__get__` and `__set__`, and so an instance variable can't be created with the same name. A non data descriptor will only call `__get__` until an instance variable with the same name is created.

Comment: Again i am unclear. you said that If `x is data descriptor` so it means if x hasn `__get__` and `__set__` defined. right? so it means x will always be a class because i can only define methods in class. If `x` is instance variable then how can i define methods like `__get__` inside a variable. This is confusing me

Comment: Yes, the definition of a data descriptor is that it has `__get__` and `__set__` defined. A non-data descriptor only has `__get__` defined. An instance variable can be an object of a class, so something like `c.a = MyClass()`. It's more about how a data descriptor user-defines modification with `__set__`, and how a non data descriptor doesn't user-define modification. I edited to try to improve clarity.

Comment: note: objects that have class with `__slots__` attribute don't have a dictionary of attributes.