# Not able to understand the instance variable descriptors in python

Tags: python

I was reading this post and few things don't get cleared

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14787522/1890488

He uses this code

```
class O4(O3):
    @property # this decorator makes this instancevar into a data descriptor
    def var(self):
        return "Data descriptors (such as properties) are high priority"

    @var.setter # I'll let O3's constructor set a value in __dict__
    def var(self, value):
        self.__dict__["var"]  = value # but I know it will be ignored
```

He says that @property converts any instance variable into data descriptor.

1. Now does it mean that it automatically defines `__get__` , `__set__` and `__del__` for that varaible

or @property is only equivalent to `__get__`

i am not getting it

2. Are there any more decorators which convert instance variables to data descriptors
3. what is the function of @var.setter. is that also the data descriptor part

Answer (score 1):

The `@property` calls the `property()` builtin, and you should consult the documentation for details of that.

`property` only has one mandatory parameter, the leftmost, the "getter".  Others are `setter` and `deleter`.

The use of a decorator with the `@` prefix is only syntactic sugar.  If you wish you can call `property` in a more conventional (if unpythonic) way:

```
def var_get(self):
    return "Data descriptors (such as properties) are high priority"

def var_set(self, value):
    self.__dict__["var"]  = value 

var = property(var_get, var_set)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the code for the property decorator on your system, you'll see that it takes three arguments:

- `fget`: A function that does the getting of the variable;
- `fset`: A function that does the setting of the variable;
- `fdel`: A function that deletes the variable.

As you normally decorate a single function with a decorator, you'll usually just define the getter:

```
@property
def my_var(self):
    return self._my_var
```

Should you wish to also declare a setter, you can use your new 'property' to include a setter, via `.setter`:

```
@my_var.setter
def my_var(self, value):
    self._my_var = value
```

The combination of the two is equivalent to calling `my_var = property(get_my_var, set_my_var)`.

Comment: From the `property` doc: *Be sure to give the additional functions the same name as the original property*.  Your `set_my_var` will give an AttributeError when used as a setter.

Comment: Your equivalent call to `property` is also suspect, since you replace `my_var` (referencing a function) with the return value of `property`.  If you are not using decorators then the function names have to be different to the attribute name.  With decorators they all use the same name.

Comment: While overwriting the variable works just fine, I've changed things to be more explicit :)