# Differences between data attributes and method attributes

Tags: python, methods, attributes

What is a method attribute, and a data attribute? What the difference between them and what they have in common?

I was reading python 2.7.9 (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#random-remarks) and suddenly  both became hard to understand.
I'll appreciate some light over it.

Comment: You're not alone in being confused. The official docs are unofficially the suckiest things that I've ever read on the Internet.

Comment: @Mugen I (and I'm also not alone) think that Python has actually one of the most helpful and best-written official docs among all programming languages. When people have trouble understanding a topic, they tend to blame everything else... except for themselves. Also, data attributes are, simply said, variables bound to an object, where method attributes (methods) are functions bound to an object.

Comment: That doesn't change my opinion about the docs. I'll just agree to disagree on this.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

An attribute is a variable that is looked up on another object using dot syntax: `obj.attribute`. The way Python is designed, attribute lookups can do a variety of things, and that variety can sometimes lead to bugs if you don't really understand what is happening (this is what the documentation you linked to warns about).

The most basic issue is that an attribute lookup can find either a value stored in the object's instance dictionary, or it can find something from the object's class (or a base class, if there's inheritance going on). Methods are functions stored in the class, but you usually use them by looking them up on an instance (which "binds" the method, inserting the object as the first arguemnt when the method is called).

The exact sequence of what is checked when is a bit complicated (I described the full process in [an answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14787334/confused-with-getattribute-and-setattribute-in-python/14787522#14787522)), but at the most basic level, instance attributes usually take precedence over class attribute.

If an instance attribute and a class attribute with the same name both exist, usually only the instance attribute will be accessible. This can be very confusing if it is unintended.

Consider the following code:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.lst = lst

    def sum(self):
        self.sum = sum(self.lst)
        return self.sum

f = Foo([1,2,3])

print(f.sum())
print(f.sum())
```

At the bottom of this code, we make two identical calls. The first works just fine, but the second will raise an exception.

This is because the first time we look up `f.sum` we find a method in the `Foo` class. We can call the method with no problems. The trouble comes from the fact that the `sum` method assigns the result of its calculation (the sum of the elements in `self.lst`) to an instance attribute also named `sum`. This hides the `sum` method from view.

When second `f.sum()` call looks up `f.sum`, it finds the instance attribute, containing the integer `6`, rather than the expected method. An integer is not callable, so we get an exception.

The solution, of course, is not to use the same name for the method and attribute. The code above is a pretty trivial example. The bugs caused by this sort of thing in more complex code can be much more difficult to figure out.

If you're writing code that adds attributes to objects you don't know much about, you should be careful to avoid common names. If you're writing a mixin class, consider using two leading underscores in the attribute names to trigger Python's name mangling, which is designed for exactly this sort of situation.

---

Addendum: It's also possible that the distinction the documentation is trying to make is between data and non-data descriptors. Methods are the most common kind of non-data descriptor, so it might make a degree of sense to call them "method attributes" (especially in contrast to "data attributes" which would be the corresponding name for data descriptors), though I'm not aware of that language being used more widely. The important difference between the two kinds of descriptors is that data descriptors (like `property`) get processed *before* the instance dictionary is checked for an ordinary instance variable. As discussed above, non-data descriptors like methods get processed only *after* the instance dictionary is checked, so they can be shadowed by data stored on the instance.

Comment: Your explanation is pretty straightforward. So, looks to me that the documentation I've linked want to means 'data attribute' = 'instance attribute', 'method attribute' = 'class attribute'. If I'm wrong please correct me.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I think that documentation may be rather old and not entirely up to date. Certainly, "instance attribute" and "class attribute" are much more common terms these days. It is also worth noting that the real situation is a bit more complicated than I presented here. Some kinds of class attributes (e.g. `property` objects) will take precedence over instance attributes. It's pretty unlikely you'd end up in that situation by mistake, however.

Comment: @Blckknght This precedence rule surprised me. I thought f.sum() is a function and is different than f.sum which is a data variable. Shouldn't it always evaluate to '6' like in C++? Looks like it found f.sum = 6 first and then tried to execute '6()' and got "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable" exception.

Comment: A similar [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39025680/does-data-attributes-override-method-attributes-in-a-class-in-python/) shows instance attributes usually take precedence over class attribute.and an instance (data) attribute hides the method with the same name

Comment: Ways of avoiding mixing methods (class attributes) with data attributes (instance attributes): "capitalizing method names, prefixing data attribute names with a small unique string (perhaps just an underscore), or using verbs for methods and nouns for data"  -- Python Tutorial 3.7.0
attributes."

Answer (score 11):

An attribute is any thing for the lack of a better word that is bound to an object, for example:

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Rufus"

    def bark(self):
        print "Woof Woof!"
```

In this case the data attribute is the name, which is simply a value that is bound to the instance of the Dog. As for a method attribute, one answer would be the bark method, as it's not so much a value as it is an action. It's just as it is in English. A data attribute is exactly as it sounds; it's data, it is simply a property. A method is a procedure, an action, and this is exactly what a method attribute is.

Comment: technically speaking name is not the value, it is a reference to the value

Answer (score 3):

An attribute is basically anything that you can do `instance.attribute_name` with. For instance in:

```
class Hello(object):
    def __init__(self, word):
        self.word = word

    def greet(self):
        print "Hello: "+self.word
```

`__init__`, `greet` and `word` would all be attributes. I would guess that a method is anything that is declared with def at the class scope (as opposed to doing self.func = lambda x:x*x for instance). In this case you get into bound vs unbound methods and the like. The important part being that for a member attribute when you do `instance.method_name` you get back a bound method, which when you call it will call the original method with the instance as the first argument.

Also, after reading some of that section their wording is somewhat confusing/erroneous. For instance they say "Data attributes override method attributes with the same name", which as far as I know would be better put as instance attribute override class attributes with the same name. From the example I gave if we expanded this to:

```
class Hello(object):
    greeting = "Hello: "
    def __init__(self, word):
        self.word = word

    def greet(self):
        print self.greeting+self.word
```

Then we could do:

```
>>> a = Hello("world")
>>> a.greeting = "Goodbye "
>>> a.greet()
"Goodbye world"
```

This due to the fact that we put an instance attribute of greeting over the class attribute of greeting. Since methods defined in the class (the usual way) are class attributes they will be overridden by any instance attributes (data or otherwise).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a straight forward explanation to your question, which has helped me understand the difference between an attribute and a method.

A class is like a set of instructions or blueprint for how to build many objects that share characteristics.

An object is a data type built according to specifications provided by the class definition.

An attribute is a value(characteristic). Think of an attribute as a variable that is stored within an object.

A method is a set of instructions. Methods are functions, which are associated with an object. Any function included in the parent class definition can be called by an object of that class.

I hope this helps.

Comment: an attribute is not the value itself, it is the variable attached to the object

Answer (score 0):

An attribute describes an object whilst a method acts on an object and changes it.