# why do we put () while calling some function and some we don't in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, function-call

```
df.shape #we check the shape of dataset
(1338, 7)
```

While calling the above shape function, we did not use () but for most of the other function we use ().
why is that?

```
df.info()# gives the info of the dataset
```

Comment: Can you give context as to what `df` is, and what `df.shape` and `df.info()` are? Are you sure that `df.shape` is not a variable rather than a function? See https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-functions-and-variables-in-python-programming

Comment: shape is a property - not a function. see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shape.htmlhttps://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shape.html

Comment: it may actually be a property

Comment: I suggest to reopen the question and close it as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46615919/why-does-head-need-and-shape-does-not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`pandas.DataFrame.shape`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shape.html) is not a function, it's a [property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618002/using-property-versus-getters-and-setters), as you can see [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/70c056becc71d1ab43cb6ef6c737b852ae89c15e/pandas/core/frame.py#L588) in the definition of `shape`:

```py
    @property
    def shape(self) -> Tuple[int, int]:
        ...
```

A property is accessed (read and written) just as if it were a regular attribute of the object, so no parentheses are used.